# Data filter using Isotop with select box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am working on data filter and I have made data filter with 3 select box.But issue is that only one(`1st`) select box is working .It is not filtering data for 2nd and 3rd.

What is issue ?

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fgLUa/127/)

Answer (score 0):

you must send each select element's filter data separately.
in this case you can set id for second and third select elements to be able to send each select filter data.

take a look at below code :

```
  $('#some').click(function(){
      var $select = $('select');
      var $select1 = $select.next();
      var $select2 = $select1.next();

      var group = $select.attr('data-filter-group');
      var group1 = $select1.attr('data-filter-group');
      var group2 = $select2.attr('data-filter-group');

      filters[ group ] = $select.find(':selected').attr('data-filter-value');
      filters[ group1 ] = $select1.find(':selected').attr('data-filter-value');
      filters[ group2 ] = $select2.find(':selected').attr('data-filter-value');
```

here is [**jsfiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/fgLUa/131/)

Comment: I have updated the code above check it at [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fgLUa/131/)

Answer (score 0):

if you use `class='option-set clearfix'` for all three select box then you can have it like this:

```
var choices = $('select[class="option-set clearfix"]');

var choice1 = choices.eq(0).val();
var choice2 = choices.eq(1).val();
var choice3 = choices.eq(2).val();
console.log(choice1);
console.log(choice2);
console.log(choice3);
```

Comment: Can you please provide JS Fiddle?